Docker build fails while trying to install atari libraries - gymnaisum[atari] : conflicts with ale-py
I am trying to build dockerfile with the below code:
FROM python:3.10  
WORKDIR /app  
COPY ./requirements.txt .  
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt  

requirements.txt is as below:
DI-engine==0.5.1
gymnasium[atari]

and the error message is like:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ale-py~=0.8.1; extra == "atari" (from shimmy[atari]) (from versions: none)
53.54 ERROR: No matching distribution found for ale-py~=0.8.1; extra == "atari"

I guess this is the similar issue:
https://github.com/Farama-Foundation/Arcade-Learning-Environment/issues/504
If I try to install ale-py first, "No matching distribution found for ale-py" error occurs again.
Also I tried with below settings:
python version w/ 3.8 ~ 3.12
tried to install ale-py 0.7.6~0.8.1
RUN pip install https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/xx/yy/ale-py-0.8.1.tar.gz

any of those did not help..
I guess it is impossible to install ale-py in docker..?
Could someone plz help?

Do you have the same problem installing the same list of packages into a plain-Python virtual environment without Docker?

No, do not occur in my virtual env, only with docker

If, from your virtual environment, you pip freeze > requirements.txt, can you use the resulting lock file successfully in Docker?  (You can include unpinned version constraints in your pyproject.toml file.)
