Cannot install ale-py in docker
I'm trying to build dockerfile as below:
FROM python:3.10
RUN pip install ale-py

If I try to build, I get error msg like:
1.436 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ale-py (from versions: none)
1.436 ERROR: No matching distribution found for ale-py

In my local env (+ also in venv with same python version) There is no problem to install ale-py
Is there any conflict between docker <-> ale-py?

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78958079/docker-build-fails-while-trying-to-install-atari-libraries-gymnaisumatari ?

so should i answer or not i dont see the answer in duplicate

There is nothing wrong  with docker or ale-py , just remove orphan containers, build and run the container its working perfectly fine.
RUN pip install ale-py installs the latest therefore if you have python 3.8 > then it should be installed perfectly

I tried all solutions that have suggested, but did not resolved
I do not know the exact cause why the error occurs,
but found a adhoc solution: install the library directly using git ->
pip install git+https://github.com/mgbellemare/Arcade-Learning-Environment.git
works for me


Update the Docker Image:
docker build --pull -t my-python-app .

Add pip Update Step:
Sometimes the default pip version in Docker is outdated. Try updating it before installing ale-py:
FROM python:3.10
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install ale-py

Install System Dependencies:
ale-py could have some system-level dependencies.
FROM python:3.10
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y 
build-essential 
libssl-dev 
libffi-dev 
python3-dev
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install ale-py

Check Python Version Inside Docker:
RUN python --version

Use Virtual Environment in Docker:
FROM python:3.10
RUN python -m venv /opt/venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install ale-py



Which one of these things is the problem?  If it's OS-level packages, what specific packages do you need, and why does it cause that pip error?  If a virtual environment helps (it's not strictly necessary in Docker), why?

Try To force a specific version, use the command: pip install ale-py==0.9.1 and then rebuild your docker image with the command: docker build --no-cache -t <image-name> .
Alternatively, you can add the library to a requirements.txt file and then run: RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt to install it.
I have just tested this and its working:
FROM python:3.10

RUN pip install ale-py==0.9.1



Thanks for comment
I have tried just right now, but not worked for me

Did you use the command to clear the cache?

yes built with --no-cache

Try docker system prune -a. This command is used to clean up your Docker environment, but it will also remove a lot of resources. Make sure you're okay with losing any stopped containers or unused images. If you decide to proceed with it, you can always retry the solutions that others have suggested.
